# COM pass function pointer (delegate) as a method parameter to ActiveX object (implemented in C#)

Tags: c#, com, activex

I'm working on a browser plugin using ActiveX/COM and I'm trying to pass a Javascript *function* to a method call so that it can be used as a callback. I've been able to get the function assigned to a property on the ActiveX object, but since the method is async all calls to the method must share the same callback.

I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7875502/function-pointer-as-a-parameter-of-com-method) existing SO question but I'm not sure if this is the exact same problem since I'm not dealing directly with function pointers.

Example of what we have **now**:

```
var obj = new MyComObject();
obj.Callback = function(id) { Console.log(id); }
obj.DoMethodCallAsync("someId");
obj.DoMethodCallAsync("someOtherId");  // Uses the same callback.
```

Example of **desired** API:

```
var obj = new MyComObject();
obj.DoMethodCallAsync("someId", function(id) { Console.log("The first ID: " + id); }
obj.DoMethodCallAsync("someOtherId", function(id) { Console.log("The second ID: " + id); }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the ActiveX is coded in C++, a JavaScript function object would be passed to an  ActiveX method as `IDispatch` interface pointer. To call back this JavaScript function, you'd need to hold on to that interference and call `IDispatch::Invoke(DISPID_VALUE, ...)` when the job is done. All params passed to [Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221479%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) will be passed to the JavaScript function.

**EDITED**: If the control is in C#, a JavaScript function would be passed as an `object` to a C# method. It can be called back this way:

```
callback.GetType().InvokeMember("[DispID=0]",
  BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public,
  null, callback, new object[] { });
```

AFAIR, the member name can also be blank:

```
callback.GetType().InvokeMember(String.Empty,
  BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public,
  null, callback, new object[] { });
```

Comment: It's C#, but I assume there's an analog via PInvoke. Thanks, I'll check that out.

Comment: It's actually easier with C#. A JavaScript callback is passed as an opaque `object` to a C# method. Then you can call it back like this: `callback.GetType().InvokeMember("[DispID=0]", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public, null, callback, new object[] { });`